# Move a <div> according to horizontal scrolling over another element

Tags: jquery

To deal with sticky-top and overflow-y: scroll properties, I need to move horizontally the heading of my table according to the table content when it reach the top of page. Check my [a link](http://boukarabila.com/alta/comparator/test.html)!demo online.

```
var distance = $('#comparator-outer-wrapper').offset().top, $window = $(window);
var comparatorHeadings = $('#headings-wrapper');
var comparatorContent = $('#comparator-inner-wrapper > .row');
var width = $(comparatorContent).width();
$window.scroll(function(){
    if ($window.scrollTop() >= distance){
        $(comparatorHeadings).addClass('on-top');
        $('> .row', comparatorHeadings).css('width', width);
    } else {
        $(comparatorHeadings).removeClass('on-top');
        $('> .row', comparatorHeadings).removeAttr('style')
    }
});
$('#comparator-inner-wrapper').mousemove(function () {
    if ($(comparatorHeadings).hasClass('on-top')){
    var origin = $('#comparator-outer-wrapper').offset().left;
    var newPosition = (origin - $(this).position().left);
    $('#headings').css('left', -Math.abs(newPosition));
   }
});
```

Due to my poor knowledge in jQuery, I guess the code can be optimized to avoid the delay while scrolling horizontally.

Any idea how I can optimize this code ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly it should be easy. You just need to swap the mousemove event with onscroll event, because mousemove is not fired when you are scrolling.

So instead of

```
$('#comparator-inner-wrapper').mousemove(function () {
  if ($(comparatorHeadings).hasClass('on-top')){
    var origin = $('#comparator-outer-wrapper').offset().left;
    var newPosition = (origin - $(this).position().left);
    $('#headings').css('left', -Math.abs(newPosition));
  }
});
```

you should use:

```
$('#comparator-outer-wrapper').scroll(function () {
  if ($(comparatorHeadings).hasClass('on-top')){
    var origin = $('#comparator-outer-wrapper').offset().left;
    var newPosition = (origin - $('#comparator-inner-wrapper').position().left);
    $('#headings').css('left', -Math.abs(newPosition));
  }
});
```